# I'm trying to get a mat-input reference using @ViewChield but it's returning undefined

Tags: angular, angular-material

HTML:

```
<mat-form-field *ngSwitchCase="'edit'">
  <input
    #myInput
    (keyup.enter)="edit()"
    [formControl]="taskTitleControl"
    matInput
  />
</mat-form-field>
```

TS:

```
export class TaskComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() title: string;
  @Input() backGroundColor: string = 'red';
  currentMode: Mode = Mode.Show;
  taskTitleControl: FormControl;
  @ViewChild('myInput') input: MatInput;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.taskTitleControl = new FormControl(this.title || '', [
      Validators.required,
    ]);
  }

  edit(): void {
    this.currentMode = this.currentMode === Mode.Edit ? Mode.Show : Mode.Edit;
    console.log(this.input);
  }
}
```

I'm also tried using a reference this way:

@ViewChild(MatInput) input: MatInput;

but still returning undefined, a strange thing is that it only returns undefined on the first click, on the second click it works what.

I don't know if ngSwitchCase may be interfering with anything.

Am I doing wrong?

Comment: This works for me, what version are you using?

Comment: 11.0.5 I'm using this version.

Comment: just to clarify, the problem was because I was using ngSwitch without Angular's change detector to update the view state, It was needed to add changeDetectorRef.detectChanges() after I change the mode in the edit method.

Answer (score 0):

if you are calling `edit()` before the View initialisation it would explain why the viewChild is `undefined`, make sure the `edit()` function is called `ngAfterViewInit` has been called.

and add a static:flase option

```
@ViewChild('myInput', { static: false }) input: ElementRef;
```

Comment: No, the edit function is not called before its initialization, it is called when the user clicks on the item.

Comment: just to clarify, the problem was because I was using ngSwitch without Angular's change detector to update the view state, It was needed to add changeDetectorRef.detectChanges() after I change the mode in the edit method.